# Trap timeouts in Parse

Tags: c#, ios, .net, parse-platform, xamarin

The Parse docs states that: "By default, all connections have a timeout of 10 seconds, so tasks will not hang indefinitely."
I have this code (from Parse web site:

```
try
{
 Task t=test.SaveAsync();
 await t;
 int j = t.Id;
}
catch (ParseException exc)
{
 if (exc.Code == ParseException.ErrorCode.ObjectNotFound)
 {
  // Uh oh, we couldn't find the object!
 }
 else
 {
  //Some other error occurred
 }
}
```

I run my app (on iPhone/Xamarin) with the network on, then I set 100% network loss, then I run the code above. I neither get an exception, nor does code reach the line after the await statement where I read the task ID. In other words, I do not know what happened.
My question is:
 How do I trap Pasre timeouts in case there is no network? Is there an event or something I can use or I have to implement it all by myself, with timers and all?

Thanks, don escamilloATgmail.com

Comment: I am not a Xamarin user, but wouldnt you need to detect the error in the block or handler for the async save - the SaveAsync method doesn't throw an exception because it successfully queues the save into the background. By the time the save times out this code has already exited the try/catch - it doesn't block for 10 seconds that is the point of asynchronous operations

Comment: How do I detect the timeout in the SaveAsync?  I found out later that there is no timeout event in Parse and had to implement it by myself. One would have thought that such a sophisticated framework would have worked out the low level details.

Comment: How you have resolved this one ? I got the same problem. If i turn off the wifi connection. it never throws any exception and gets freezed there.